# How to insert text into a formated popup window with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following code works but it replaces the whole new window.

`var v = window.open("popup.html" ... );
 w.document.body.write("asd");`

I have a

```
<div id="insert-here"></div>
```

in my popup.html and I want to insert the text that I want here.

This code is not working and I tried 3 other different methods but with no luck:

```
$(w.document.body).find("#insert-here").append(msg);
```

How can I achieve it? I want to avoid creating a whole html page with css in javascript.

Comment: $("#insert-here", w.document).html(msg)

Comment: but mind that the window opening is asynchronous and takes some time, so it won't work if you put it just after the window.open... To do it properly you should wait for that new window's onLoad event.

Comment: @rupps, why don't you just write an answer? ;)

Comment: @i too short for an answer :P

Comment: ok this code is still not working it says "undefined is not a function":
$( popWindow.document ).ready(function() {
            console.log( "ready!" );
            popWindow.document.$("#insert-here").append(msg);
        });

Answer (score 1):

Could you make use of jQuery UI dialog? https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

You can have a div with some info in it:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" style="display: none;">Some information</div>
```

Then your jQuery can handle it accordingly:

```
$('#dialog').dialog();
$('#dialog').html("some other info");
```

See this jsfiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/gL3uZ/1/

Comment: my main goal would be to create a node-webkit app. You create some messages that you need and a time stamp on them. When the time is right these windows will appear with the setup text that the user created.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if this is what you're looking for. Just input the url to your popup and link up the same css page. You can obviously adjust the size to fit your needs.

```
function showPopup(url) {
            var newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=220,width=560,top=200,left=300,resizable');
            if (window.focus) {
                newwindow.focus()
            }
        }
```

---

EDIT/UPDATE: Try with an overlay?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> blah </title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="copyme">hi there</div>
<button>click</button>
<script>
(function() { 
var copyme = document.getElementById('copyme').innerHTML;
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    var overlayDiv = document.createElement('DIV'),
        overlay = overlayDiv.style; // DRY
        overlayDiv.id = 'overlay';
        overlay.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
        overlay.width = window.innerWidth + "px";
        overlay.top = window.pageYOffset + "px";
        overlay.left = window.pageXOffset + "px";
        overlay.background = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)';

    var popup = document.createElement('DIV'),
        popupCopy = document.createTextNode(copyme);
        popup.classList.add('popup');
        popup.style.color = 'white';
        popup.appendChild(popupCopy);

        overlayDiv.appendChild(popup);
        document.body.appendChild(overlayDiv);
    }, false);
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Its ugly, but you can add resize or scroll listeners and style up the inner DIV to look the way you want. That's all I got!

Comment: I can create new windows. What I cant do is take a text from the main window and copy that into the new window.

Comment: Does is HAVE to be a popup window? Could we simulate a popup window?are you against just creating an overlay and displaying the content inside a DIV appended to the overlay?

Comment: my main goal would be to create a node-webkit app. You create some messages that you need and a time stamp on them. When the time is right these windows will appear with the setup text that the user created.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found something else:

in my popup.html I need to have a little javascript code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        console.log( "ready!" );
        $("#insert-here").append(opener.msg);
    });
```

This opener will find the variable msg from my main.js file that saves text from an input field.

Comment: That is exactly what "rupps" was talking about in the comment #2.

Comment: nu. rupps said inly the "ready" and that did not work with my code that time. My solution is the "opener" part. I don't even need the ready because I have this script in the popup.html.

Comment: You probably need this: `var v = window.open("popup.html" ... ); $(w.document).ready(function(){ $("#insert-here", w.document).html(msg); });`